# How do I show that a series only has a finite number of terms $\not=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given
$$g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n!x)}{n!}$$
show that, if $\frac{x}{\pi}\in \mathbb Q$, then the series only has a finite number of terms that are not $0$.

If $\frac{x}{\pi}\in \mathbb Q$ it means that $x=\frac{q}{p}\pi$, where $q$ and $p$ are integers.
$$g(\frac{q}{p}\pi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(n!\frac{q}{p}\pi)}{n!}$$
The terms of the sum are equal to $0$ if
$$\sin(n!\frac{q}{p}\pi)=0$$
$$n!\frac{q}{p}\pi=k\pi$$
$$n!=k\frac{p}{q}$$
Where k is an integer.
Now, does this equation has infinite solutions since k can take on infinite values?
And even if this is true, it does not lead us to conclude that the terms $\not=0$ are finite, does it? There could be infinite terms $\not=0$ and yet infinite terms $=0$.
I really don't know how to prove what the exercise asks.

Comment: For every $n\geq p$, $p$ divides $n!$, so $\sin(\frac{n!} p  q \pi)=0$

Comment: @Desperado thank you, I hadn't thought about that